# Vertical align in bootstrap menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

height on the`.navbar`container and since that is the menu not vertical anymore. `display:inline-block` didn't worked for me. There must be a solution without giving the menu a padding to fix it.

How do i get the menu vertical align into the `.navbar` container? Im using bootstrap as framework

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydbuyxse/)

```
.navbar{background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #bed970, #54c1b5);background-size: 100% 4px;background-position: 0 0;background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #c8cacc;box-shadow: 0 0 4px #c8cacc;border: none;font-size: 14px;min-height: 70px;}
```

Comment: Why `min-height` ? If that is required then adjust the `line-height` for the anchors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep your height of 70px the simplest solution is to change the line-height as per CodeRomeos comment above.

```
 .navbar-brand, .navbar-nav li a {
 line-height: 40px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hnyadr4s/1/

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that min-height is being set to 70px on the .nav element

if you add the following css

```
.navbar{min-height:inherit;}
```

then it should be ok

https://jsfiddle.net/ogvs98LL/

or you can add padding to the top if you want to keep the height

https://jsfiddle.net/pfjL9jy6/